# What is the difference between the following npm install statements?

Tags: npm, npm-install

`npm install @uiw/react-monacoeditor --save`

VS

`npm i @uiw/react-monacoeditor`

What is the difference between following npm install statements when to use --save flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently they will not differ at all. Since NPM 5 packages are automatically saved into package.json dependencies when installed.

npm I is the short version of npm install so that part of the command does not differ at all either.

You can read more about the install command here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

And there is does say “ npm install saves any specified packages into dependencies by default.”